# View Pager Layout Android With LoopingViewPager want a many item scroll effect?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a view pager with LoopingViewPager this library for infinite scroll ,
i want to have swipe like if   i  swipe with speed it will swipe through 2-3 items ..depends on the speed of scrolling .. it will through that many items?
How do i  implement this ?

THESE classes along with two classes of library in same package...others things are working perfectly ...i want that scroll effect

```
VIEWPAGER_ITEM.XML
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:padding="10dp" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Rank" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/rank"
              android:text="rank"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
              android:text="country label"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/country"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
              android:text="country"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
              android:text="population label"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
               />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/population"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/country"
              android:text="population"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/populationlabel" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/flag"
              android:src="@drawable/brazil"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:background="#000000"
              android:padding="1dp" />

      </RelativeLayout>


      VIEWPAGER_MAIN.XML
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/main_viewpager"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:weightSum="4"
          android:orientation="vertical"
           >

          <com.gdgvit.vitRiviera.LoopViewPager
              android:id="@+id/view_pager_4"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/india" >
          </com.gdgvit.vitRiviera.LoopViewPager>

          <com.gdgvit.vitRiviera.LoopViewPager
              android:id="@+id/view_pager_3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/brazil" >
          </com.gdgvit.vitRiviera.LoopViewPager>

          <com.gdgvit.vitRiviera.LoopViewPager
              android:id="@+id/view_pager_1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/china" >
          </com.gdgvit.vitRiviera.LoopViewPager>

          <com.gdgvit.vitRiviera.LoopViewPager
              android:id="@+id/view_pager_2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@drawable/pakistan" >
          </com.gdgvit.vitRiviera.LoopViewPager>

      </LinearLayout>

     HOME_Fragment.java
             package com.gdgvit.vitRiviera;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
        ViewPager vp1, vp2, vp3, vp4;
        PagerAdapter adapter, adapter2;
        String[] rank;
        String[] country;
        String[] population;
        int[] flag;

        MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;

        public HomeFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View metal = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_main, container,
                    false);
            // /////////////////////////////
            rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

            country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
                    "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh",
                    "Russia", "Japan" };

            population = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422",
                    "315,761,000", "237,641,326", "193,946,886", "182,912,000",
                    "170,901,000", "152,518,015", "143,369,806", "127,360,000" };

            flag = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india,
                                R.drawable.unitedstates, R.drawable.indonesia,
                    R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.nigeria,
                    R.drawable.bangladesh, R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.japan };

            // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
            vp1 = (ViewPager) metal.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_1);
            // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), rank, country,
                    population, flag);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
            vp1.setAdapter(adapter);
            vp2 = (ViewPager) metal.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_2);
            // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
            myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
            vp2.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
            vp3 = (ViewPager) metal.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_3);
            // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
            myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
            vp3.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
            vp4 = (ViewPager) metal.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_4);
            // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
            myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
            vp4.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);


            // /////////////////////
            return metal;
        }

        private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            int NumberOfPages = 5;

            int[] res = { android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert,
                    android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
                    android.R.drawable.ic_menu_compass,
                    android.R.drawable.ic_menu_directions,
                    android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery };
            int[] backgroundcolor = { 0xFF101010, 0xFF202020, 0xFF303030,
                    0xFF404040, 0xFF505050 };

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return NumberOfPages;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

                TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                textView.setTextSize(30);
                textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(position));

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                imageView.setImageResource(res[position]);
                LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundcolor[position]);
                layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                layout.addView(textView);
                layout.addView(imageView);

                final int page = position;
                layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Page " + page + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

                container.addView(layout);
                return layout;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
            }

        }

    }

   view_pager_adapter.java

           package com.gdgvit.vitRiviera;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        String[] rank;
        String[] country;
        String[] population;
        int[] flag;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] rank, String[] country,
                String[] population, int[] flag) {
            this.context = context;
            this.rank = rank;
            this.country = country;
            this.population = population;
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return rank.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            // Declare Variables
            TextView txtrank;
            TextView txtcountry;
            TextView txtpopulation;
            ImageView imgflag;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                    false);

            // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
            txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
            txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
            txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

            // Capture position and set to the TextViews
            txtrank.setText(rank[position]);
            txtcountry.setText(country[position]);
            txtpopulation.setText(population[position]);

            // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
            imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            // Capture position and set to the ImageView
            imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

            // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I don't what to try..is there any other layout available for this?

Comment: We really need to see some code or at least a link to that other library.

Comment: https://github.com/imbryk/LoopingViewPager